# Vaadin7: Use BrowserWindowOpener and determine the URL on demand

Tags: java, vaadin

I cannot find a way to open a new Window with the new `BrowserWindowOpener` class and determine the URL to be opened on demand.

I tried overriding `handleConnectorRequest()` but it's not called when the user clicks the component.

The use of the `BrowserWindowOpener` looks something like this:

```
  OnDemandWindowParameterProvider windowParameterProvider = new OnDemandWindowParameterProvider() {

  @Override
  public String getWindowName () {
    return "window-name";
  }

  @Override
  public String getUrlOndemand () {
    return "www.google.ch";
  }
  };
  OnDemandBrowserWindowOpener opener = new OnDemandBrowserWindowOpener(windowParameterProvider);
  opener.extend(label);
```

The class `OnDemandBrowserWindowOpener` calls the two methods on the `OnDemandWindowParameterProvider` to determine both `windowName` and URL when `handleConnectorRequest()` is called. This however does not work.

Comment: How do you use the WindowOpener? Please give some example code.

Answer (score 0):

What is when you overwrite the method `public void attach()`? Is it to late for your needs?

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem, what to do ?
OK I got some solution https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/4731272/4731271